# MongoDB/Express API doesn't update entry but returns 200

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I am currently working to solve an issue in my React web app that is not allowing me to update entries in the Mongo database. I get post new documents and get all entries easily, however when I am attempting to update a portion of one, I receive a 200 response but the document is never updated. Here is the call from my react app:

```
fetch(API + this.state.project.pin, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: updatedFunctions
})
```

and the corresponding Express code

```
 app.post('/:pin', (req, res) => {

  db.collection('projects').update({pin:req.params}, {$set: {functions:req.body}}, function(err, count, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log('saved to database')
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})
```

Does anyone know where this is getting sent in the wrong direction? According to my logic, it should replace the function field in the document with the matching pin with the "updatedFunctions" object.

Comment: Please add if you are seeing either of your log statements. I believe the error is elsewhere. Are you sure, this is the correct route and the only implementation of said route?

Comment: There is a app.get('/:pin'), but that shouldnt interfere if the header has a post in it correct? It is logging and getting redirected.

Comment: If it is getting redirected, then there usually is no HTTP 200 result, but a HTTP 3xx one...

Answer (score 1):

Your search criteria seems wrong:

```
db.collection('projects').update({pin: req.params.pin}, [...]
```

Your version would search for an object in the `pin` key. This now searches for a scalar/string in the `pin` key.

Comment: This worked, but now pre-existing "functions" object is replaced by an empty object.